# Artin chapter 2 exercises

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I've written some solutions to Artin's exercises. Can someone please verify them?

> Assume the equation $xyz = 1$ holds for a group $G$. Does it follow that $yzx=1$? That $yxz=1$?

We first show that $yzx = 1$:
\begin{eqnarray}
xyz&=&1 \\
yz&=&x^{-1} \\
yzx&=&x^{-1}x \\
yzx&=&1
\end{eqnarray}

We then show that $yxz \neq 1$, unless $x$ and $z$ commute:

\begin{eqnarray}
xyz &=&1\\
yz&=&x^{-1}\\
y&=&x^{-1}z^{-1}\\
yxz&=&x^{-1}z^{-1}xz\\
yzx&=&(zx)^{-1}(xz)
\end{eqnarray}

> Let $S$ be any set. Prove that the law of composition defined by $ab=a$ is associative.

Let $a,b,c \in S$. Then,

\begin{equation}
a(bc)=ab=a
\end{equation}
Also,
\begin{equation}
(ab)c=ac=a
\end{equation}

> Determine the elements of the cyclic group generated by $\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 1 \\
> -1 & 0
> \end{bmatrix}$ explicitly.

$H = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\  0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$

> Let $a,b$ be elements of an abelian group of orders $m$ and $n$, respectively. What can you say about the order of their product $ab$?

The order of $ab$ is the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Actually, you have not shown that $yxz \neq 1$. What you have proven is that if $x$ and $z$ commute, then $yzx = 1$. Also, your last answer lacks a proof.

Comment: You are much more likely to get a response if you don't make reviewing your handful of proofs more tedious than it would be if you posted each proof separately.